# Does anyone know whether the Kotzker and the Ishbitzer were related in anyway?

Tags: chasidut-hasidism

I am trying to figure out whether the Kotzker was related in anyway to the Ishbitzer dynasty (I know the history of their relationship, my question is whether they were related thru marriage in any way). If so, how? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Zak and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!